# 70's book: black woman held prisoner on a spaceship becomes captain after a mutiny

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember the name of the main character, only that she is a black woman and is a prisoner on a spaceship. There is a mutiny on the ship and she becomes captain after the captain becomes ill.

Comment: Can you provide any more details? Such as when you may have read it, when it was published, any character names or the style of the author? (Sorry I don’t know why I thought this was about a tv show)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for [Zelde M'Tana](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1156486.Zelde_M_Tana) by F.M. Busby.

Zelda was a street kid who became leader of a gang but was captured and sent offworld when she got involved in a mutiny. After becoming captain, she joined Bran Tregare's revolt against the UET, the rulers of Earth and its colonies.

[image]